# How do I keep first, if value of row1 column1 == row2 column2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check all rows in dataframe,

- if **this row**'s `column1` == **previous row**'s `column2`

  and
- if **this row**'s `column2` == **previous row**'s `column1`

then drop this row.

---

For example:

```
 Column1    Column2 
    A          B
    B          A
    A          C
    A          D
    D          A
    B          C
```

The result I want would be:

```
 Column1    Column2 
    A          B
    A          C
    A          D
    B          C
```

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
m1 = df['Column1'] == df['Column2'].shift()
m2 = df['Column2'] == df['Column1'].shift()

out = df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

```
print(out)

  Column1 Column2
0       A       B
2       A       C
3       A       D
5       B       C
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a shift on those columns then use conditional statement to check if the column values are equal.

```
import pandas as pd


data = [
    ['A',          'B'],
    ['B',          'A'],
    ['A',          'C'],
    ['A',          'D'],
    ['D',          'A'],
    ['B',          'C']]

cols = ['Column1', 'Column2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

df['Pre_Column2'] = df['Column2'].shift(1)
df['Pre_Column1'] = df['Column1'].shift(1)

df = df[~((df['Column1'] == df['Pre_Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == df['Pre_Column1']))]
df = df[cols]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
  Column1 Column2
0       A       B
2       A       C
3       A       D
5       B       C
```